# Getting error with working Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Getting error when copy  database file

error is

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.clppl.project/database/clppl.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)**

Here My **DatabaseHandler** class

```
  public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    //The Androids default system path of your application database.
    String DB_PATH =null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "clppl.sqlite";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase; 
    private final Context myContext;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
     * @param context
     */
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/assets/"; 
    }   

  /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            //database does't exist yet.

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
```

Java code where I am calling to open databse

```
 myDbHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);

         try {

          myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
         try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBase();


            }catch(SQLException sqle){

                throw sqle;

            }
```

Comment: Make sure you check for the database file exists in your assets or not.

Comment: yes sure db file exists in assets folder

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ?

Comment: File not found error occur when debugg Code

Comment: Try changing `DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/assets/";` to `DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/databases/";`

Comment: @Aniruddha not working both path problem occur when copy database

Comment: `myDbHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);`. What is `context` in that? Why don't you change it to `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);` and initialise your DB_PATH as `DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/databases/";`

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.clppl.project/database/clppl.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)    this error occur when copy database file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrongly defined your `DB_PATH`. Your database will resides inside `databases` folder in your application's package directory not inside `assets` folder. There won't be created any `assets` folder.

Change your path as below:

```
      DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/databases/";
```

instead of

```
       DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/assets/";
```

Comment: @Kuldeep Change your path like this . `DB_PATH="/data/data/com.clppl.project/database/";`

Comment: @GrIsHu it is `databases` not `database`. I guess you mistyped it as `database`.

Comment: @Aniruddha Yes, Its was mistyped. Thanks :)

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.clppl.project/database/clppl.sqlite: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) this error ocuur

Comment: Make sure that the `databases` folder is created from your `File Explorer`. @Kuldeep And its not `database` its `databases`.